Como contar los registros de una tabla que cumplen unas caracteristicas
Os adjunto un esquema de las tablas, lo he simplificado. Os cuento un poco.
Hay una tabla llamada Temas, la cual contienes datos generales, imaginemos que son Coche, Moto, Avion, Barco, etc.
La tabla Categorias contiene distintos tipos de categorias relacionadas con cada tema, que no tienen por que ser iguales. Para Coche puede ser maletero, puerta, capo. Para Moto puede ser carenado, manillar. Para Avion puede ser alas, flaps.
Y luego hay cuatro tablas que tienen partes de trabajo, de los tipos 1 al 4.
Cada Categoria puede tener n partes de los distintos tipos o ninguno.
Lo que me esta volviendo loco, es que necesito saber alguna forma de actualizar los campos cat_sum_p1, cat_sum_p2, cat_sum_p3, cat_sum_p4. Estos campos lo que tienen es el numero de registros que hay en las tablas de partes para cada categoría.
Me da igual si se actualiza solo al abrir la pagina, o si lo hace al pinchar un iconito, eso me da igual, pero el UPDATE me tiene perdido, me lio con los Count y las agrupaciones... en fin cosas de no saber.
Espero explicarme bien, si no es asi (ya sabéis que uno a si mismo se lo explica de maravilla), decirme e intento ponerlo mas claro.
Mil gracias anticipadas a tod@s los ayudáis con vuestros conocimientos.


La mejor idea sería no tener estas columnas. No queremos guardar datos redundantes. Siempre puedes contar los registros, entonces esas columnas no tienen ninguna información adicional.

Otro consejo: No está necesario llamar las columnas con un parte del nombre de la tabla. "descripcion" es suficiente,  no tienes que llamarlo "tem_descripcion". En una consulta puedes añadir el nombre o alias de la tabla: temas.descripcion o tem.descripcion. Y sea consistente con los nombres en tu base de datos. Una columna de identificación tiene "id" en su nombre. Entonces no "categorías.cat_tema", sino "categorías.id_tema" o algo semejante.

Coincido con Thorsten, normalmente los count no se almacenan, se lanza la consulta cuando hace falta para generar un informe o lo que sea. Por otro lado, el nombre "sum" resulta un poco confuso porque lo que quieres hacer es contar y no sumar nada.

Por último, lo que quieres se puede hacer con un trigger, es decir un proceso que se ejecuta automáticamente cada vez que insertas en un tabla. Puedes programar el trigger para que cada vez que insertes en Parte 1, Parte 2, ... incremente el contador correspondiente en Categorías.

Vale, entiendo lo que me decis, lo de no almacenar un dato innecesario y quitar esos campos sum (que razon es contar no sumar) de la tabla.

Vere de revisar la nomenclatura para que sea mas clara la definicion de los campos y tablas, perdonar pero soy autodidacta y voy a prendiendo sobre la marcha

Algun ejemplo de como realizar los count, he mirado por la web y me lio con el tema de los group by y al fin termino cansado de darme con una pared

Lo siento, tu pregunta carece de un [example], y no sigue las normas de [ask] y parece que buscas opiniones en lugar de una respuesta concreta a un caso concreto, lo cual es motivo de cierre segun las directrices de este sitio, que no es un foro. Para encontrar ejemplos de count y groupby google y las IA te mostrarán un montón. Puedes [edit] tu pregunta agregando un caso concreto, con el código que has realizado, y los errores que te da, para que podamos ayudarte mejor y así podrás validar y aceptar la respuesta que mejor te hayan dado, tal como marca la dinámica del sitio.

Ah vale perdon, no queria molestar, entiendo lo que comentas, voy a seguir intentandolo entonces yo y si eso ya os pregunto con un codigo con el que este trabajando. Mil gracias.

Dijiste que eres autodidacta.. que guardas en las tablas parte 1 a parte 4?? porque esas tablas, no suena que esten bien tampoco.. para mi, esa base no esta normalizada y por eso te estas haciendo lio...

@gbianchi dudo que el OP conosca que es una tabla o base de datos normalizada ...

Pienso que lo que quiere decir gbianchi es que las cuatro tablas se parecen y sería mejor tener una sola tabla en vez con una columna para el parte (1 a 4). Sin embargo, esto no tiene nada que ver con normalización de bases de datos.

@ThorstenKettner apostaria que son categorias y subcategorias o cosas asi.. porque por algo, los quiere contar... es raro... y si.. tiene todo que ver con normalizar esa DB...
